# How to rewrite semigroup as $ P_t=e^{-Lt} $?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, analysis, markov-chains

For a Markov process  $X_t$ with semigroup $P_t$, we have
$$
P_t f=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x].
$$

How to rewrite it as
$$
P_t=e^{-Lt}
$$
where $L$ is the generator of $P_t$, that means
$$
Lf=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{P_tf-f}{t}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thorough treatment can be found here: [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/notes/lecture-12.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/754/notes/lecture-12.pdf)

The upshot is that, for a given $f$, we can define
\begin{align*}
u_t(x)
= (P_t f)(x)
\end{align*}
and compute its derivative $\partial_t$ from the fact that, since $P$ is a semigroup, $u_{t + h} = P_{t + h} f = P_h u_t$.
Hence, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{u_{t+h}(x) - u_t(x)}{h}
= \biggl[\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{P_h u_t - u_t}{h}\biggr](x)
= L u_t(x).
\end{align*}

In particular, we have the differential equation for all $x$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u_t(x) = (L u_t)(x), \quad u_0(x) = f(x),
\end{align*}
which we can check is solved by
\begin{align*}
u_t
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} L^n f
= e^{tL} f,
\end{align*}
and hence $P_t = e^{tL}$.

Now, there are a whole bunch of issues with convergence and swapping the order of limits that this explanation sweeps under the rug, all of which are addressed in the supplied reference.

Comment: Can I ask why $u_t=e^{tL}f$ solve the above differential equation?

Comment: Differentiating the power series, we have that $\partial_t\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} L^n f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} L^n f (x) = L\sum_{n'=0}^\infty \frac{t^{n'}}{n'!} L^{n'} f(x) = L u_t(x)$